kableExtra not recognizing qwrap2 styling
I recently updated my R and Rstudio, and now kable doesn't seem to recognizing styling from qwraps2. Here's a reproducible example with the output I get in Viewer.
options(qwraps2_markup = "markdown")
summary_statistics <-
  list(
    "Sepal Length" =
      list(
        "N (%)" = ~qwraps2::n_perc0(!is.na(Sepal.Length), na_rm = TRUE),
        "Mean (SD)" = ~paste0(round(mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm = T), 1), ' (', 
                              round(sd(Sepal.Length, na.rm = T), 1), ')')
      ),
    "Sepal Width" =
      list(
        "N (%)" = ~qwraps2::n_perc0(!is.na(Sepal.Width), na_rm = TRUE),
        "Mean (SD)" = ~paste0(round(mean(Sepal.Width, na.rm = T), 1), ' (', 
                              round(sd(Sepal.Width, na.rm = T), 1), ')')
      )
  )

tbl <- summary_table(iris, summary_statistics, by = 'Species')
colnames(tbl) <- gsub('\\(', '\\<br\\/\\>\\(', colnames(tbl))

kable(tbl, col.names = colnames(tbl), escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  pack_rows('Sepal Length', 1, 2) %>%
  pack_rows('Sepal Width', 3, 4)


UPDATE: Styling issue is fixed by using kbl(). However, is there an option so that the header row for each section is not repeated from summary_statistics and pack_rows? Would like to keep the header rows from pack_rows instead.


Use kbl(), not kable().

Thanks, that worked! Is there an option so that the header row for each section is not repeated from summary_statistics and pack_rows? Would like to keep the header rows from pack_rows instead.

This problem is a result of qwraps2 trying to format the text and having kableExtra then trying for format the formatted text.  This is known issue and will be addressed in a future release of qwraps2
